# MVC3 Forms Authentication - going online

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I'm using the AuthorizeAttribute and the default forms authentication that comes with the "Internet Application" preset.

Everything is working as it should, but I have some questions about deployment.

I've got this in the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="AlltForMusikContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|AlltForMusik.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I tried to get it to use the database in "AlltForMusikContext" but with no success. When I deploy the site, I will only have one (1) SQL-database.

How does this work really? Is the "aspnetdb.mdf" some special db or do I need to get it to use the db in "AlltForMusikContext"?

I couldn't find any relevant info about this, so I would really appreciate your input!

Best regards
Mikael

Answer (score 0):

you are right, your application is having default "aspnetdb.mdf" in you application under "App_Data" folder.
putting AspNetDb.mdf file  under application folder is not a good practice rather than you can create a separate database with name and use that. putting your membership database along with your application database does not make good sense.

Comment: Once I go online I will use a MSSQL-db and not the .mdf. But are you suggesting that I use the MSSQL-db for the application, and a seperate .mdf-db for the users? Do web hosts normally allow .mdf-dbs? I guess I have to check it up on my particular web host. I though the "App_Data" folder was "safe", and that it restricted users from accessing it?